Узнать время последней поправки в таблице
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM bd LIKE 'table'

Мне интересно значение Update_time, вопрос немного в другом. Достать значение сразу 2-3 таблиц, возможно за один запрос?

Ну вот документация упоминает WHERE, значит должно быть возможно написать что-то вроде SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM bd WHERE Name IN ('table1', 'table2');

Не выходит, там через where указывается база данных и таблица. Пробовал, не выходит...

Не очень понятно что конкретно не выходит, я проверял свой комментарий перед отправкой и на моих базах данных всё успешно вышло

У меня только о последней информацию достает, что в in
